# How to validate geographic coordinates?

Tags: java, swing, validation, gps, coordinates

I'm trying to validate the text of a `JTextField`. The content of this textfield should be something like this `66.160507, -153.369141` or `66.160507,-153.369141` (without whitespace after the comma).
So far I validate only the range for both latitude and longitude.
Here:

```
 String [] splitted = jtextField.getText().split(",");
 double latitude = Double.parseDouble(splitted[0]);
 double longitude = Double.parseDouble(splitted[1])

if(latitude < -90 || latitude > 90)
  return false;
else
  continue;

if(longitude < -180 || longitude > 180)
      return false;
    else
      continue;
```

but now how can I check whether the text in the `JTextField` is in the right format and order? I need to validate these two cases:

```
must be a double -> must be a comma -> must be a whitespace -> must be a double 
must be a double -> must be a comma -> must be a double
```

Comment: Not what you asked, but you want `||` (which means "or") instead of `and` in both of your `if` conditions.  And you don't need `else continue;`.

Comment: Use `JFormattedTextField` to restrict the type of input (ie decimal values only), you'll still need to valid the ranges

Comment: @MadProgrammer sounds like an answer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks, though I would still need to check that everything is in the right sequence.

Comment: @JaneLilep I would have a seperate field for `latitude` and `longitude`, what the `JFormattedText` field do is ensure that the user only enters numerical data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use a regular expression to validate the form of what's in your text field.  You can read up on the different symbols you can use in a regular expression at [the Javadoc for the Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but some of the ones you might use would be

- `*` any number of matches of what goes before (including none);
- `+` one or more matches of what goes before;
- `?` zero or one matches of what goes before;
- `[ ]` a range of characters.
- `\.` a dot (the backslash will need escaping if it's in a Java `String` literal),
- `\s` any whitespace (and this backslash will also need escaping in a `String` literal).

Putting this all together you might come up with a regular expression like this.

```
-?[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?,\s*-?[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?
```

to match a pair of latitude and longitude.

This matches

- optionally a minus sign,
- a number other than 0, for the first digit,
- any number of other digits (even none),
- optionally, a sequence consisting of a decimal point, then any number of other digits,
- a comma,
- any number of whitespace characters (even none),
- the first four bullet points in this paragraph, all over again.

You could then write code like this.

```
String textValue = jtextField.getText();
String twoDoublesRegularExpression = "-?[1-9][0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+)?,\\s*-?[1-9][0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+)?";

if (textValue.matches(twoDoublesRegularExpression)) {
    // this value is OK
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much but this regex works with the following input "43,90321" when it shouldn't. Also it works fine with this "13.90,12.91" but doesn't work with this "13.90, 12.91" (whitespace after the comma).

Comment: So you might need some tweaking.  I think `43,90231` will be caught in your range check, since 90231 is not between -180 and 180.  The regular expression only checks that you've got two numbers separated by a comma.  And if you want a space to be possible, then you can put a space and a `*` in the regular expression at the right place.

Comment: I've edited the answer to allow any amount of whitespace in the input.  I misread the bit of your question where you said "without whitespace after the comma".

Comment: Again, thanks so much! I have to study regex since I never used them. May I ask you one more thing? I don't know if I should ask a new question... anyway, what's the difference between this regex `([+-]?\d+\.?\d+)\s*,\s*([+-]?\d+\.?\d+)` and yours? For instance, yours accept the input "3,3" but the other one doesn't.

Comment: Well, there are a few differences; but I think the key one is that your expression has `\d+\.?\d+` for the numeric parts.  Now `\d` is just a shorthand for `[0-9]`; but the `+` means "one or more".  So this is one or more digits, then optionally a dot, then one or more digits again.  So even when there's no dot, there have to be at least two digits to match this regular expression.  That's why `3` doesn't match it in your example.

Comment: Hi, I have one more question for you if you don't mind. I've noticed you put **[1-9]** at the start because you want to avoid something like "03" but the thing is I can have some numbers that starts with 0, like "0.1" or "0.2" and so on. So, how can I fix this?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Maybe you could try something like `(0|[1-9][0-9]*)` so that you can have _either_ a single zero, _or_ a number that doesn't start with zero.  The `|` symbol means "or".

Answer (score 1):

###### I use regex to validate longitude and latitude:

###### **longitude**:

`^[-+]?(180(\\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\\d)|([1-9]?\\d))(\\.\\d+)?)$`

###### **latitude**:

`^[-+]?([1-8]?\\d(\\.\\d+)?|90(\\.0+)?)$`

```
    public boolean validateLong(String longitude) {
        booelan isValid = false;
        if (longitude != null) {
            String regexValidateLongitude = "^[-+]?(180(\\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\\d)|([1-9]?\\d))(\\.\\d+)?)$";
            isValid = longitude.trim().matches(regexValidateLongitude);
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    public boolean validateLat(String latitude) {
        booelan isValid = false;
        if (latitude != null) {
            String regexValidateLatitude = "^[-+]?([1-8]?\\d(\\.\\d+)?|90(\\.0+)?)$";
            isValid = latitude.matches(regexValidateLatitude);
        }
        return  isValid;

    }
```